# Radix Sort on an array of BigInteger

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to sort a randomized array of type BigInteger using the radix sort algorithm. The algorithm I am trying to use is written below.

```
    public static void radixSort(int[] input) {
        final int RADIX = 10;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<Integer>[] bucket = new ArrayList[RADIX];

        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
            bucket[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

        boolean maxLength = false;
        int tmp = -1, placement = 1;
        while (!maxLength) {
            maxLength = true;

            for (Integer i : input) {
                tmp = i / placement;
                bucket[tmp % RADIX].add(i);
                if (maxLength && tmp > 0) {
                    maxLength = false;
                }
            }

            int a = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < RADIX; b++) {
                for (Integer i : bucket[b]) {
                    input[a++] = i;
                }
                bucket[b].clear();
            }

            placement *= RADIX;
        }
    }
```

I have been trying for a while now but I keep running into error after error, so what do I need to change in the code above in order for it to sort BigInteger instead of int? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing what you're doing with `BigInteger`.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code and added a driver code also:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Radix {
    public static void radixSort(BigInteger[] input) {
        final int RADIX = 10;
        final BigInteger BIG_RADIX = BigInteger.valueOf(new Integer(RADIX).intValue());

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<BigInteger>[] bucket = new ArrayList[RADIX];

        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
            bucket[i] = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        }

        boolean maxLength = false;
        BigInteger tmp = null;
        int placement = 1;
        while (!maxLength) {
            maxLength = true;

            for (BigInteger i : input) {
                tmp = i.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(new Integer(placement).intValue()));
                bucket[(tmp.mod(BIG_RADIX).intValue())].add(i);
                if (maxLength && tmp.signum() ==1) {
                    maxLength = false;
                }
            }

            int a = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < RADIX; b++) {
                for (BigInteger i : bucket[b]) {
                    input[a++] = i;
                }
                bucket[b].clear();
            }
            placement *= RADIX;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger[] input = new BigInteger[5];
        input[0] = new BigInteger("12345678");
        input[1] = new BigInteger("45465768");
        input[2] = new BigInteger("45466771");
        input[3] = new BigInteger("13243546");
        input[4] = new BigInteger("98765456");

        radixSort(input);
        for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(input[i]+" ");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You can make it more efficient.